# How can I use PopupWindow in Xamarin android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use PopupWindow to inflate layout, but I have not found any example in internet. Could you teach me how to use it.

This is my current code but it is not showing popupWindow

```
private void ShowMenu(ImageButton anchor, Dictionary<string, object> data)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    View popupView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.menu_outlet_buttons, null);

    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
    bool focusable = true;

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView.Context);
    popupWindow.ShowAtLocation(_view, GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
}
```

By the way this is an Adapter

```
public MyAdapter(List<Dictionary<string, object>> data, Context context)
{
    _data = data;
    _context = context;
}
```

This is my reference, but I could not reproduce the same in Xamarin Android.

[How to create a popup window (PopupWindow) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/how-to-create-a-popup-window-popupwindow-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you create the instance of the PopupWindow is wrong. I tried the following code in my project, it worked well:

```
View view =  LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.popup, null);
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,true);
popupWindow.ShowAtLocation(view, GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
```

Update:

I had checked the popupWindow.ShowAtLocation method, the first parameter is the parent view.

And you can get the x,y by the following code:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
imagebutton.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
```

Comment: Did you declare this? ``LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);``

Comment: Is my declaration in ``inflater`` is correct?

Comment: It seems that we needn't to declare this in xamarin.android. Of course ,if do that also ok.@Elohist

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you. But I want to inflate this on ``anchor``. Could you teach me how to do this?

Comment: I can't understand ' inflate this on anchor' clearly, can you show more detail or post a new question?@Elohist

Comment: Because it inflate only at the center of the screen. I want to inflate it on certain object which is the ``ImageButton achor``

Comment: ``PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(_context, anchor);`` Actually this my code before in ``PopupMenu`` which receives the achor parameter

Comment: The popupWindow.ShowAtLocation decide the location of the popupWindow, you can get the X, Y of the  ImageButton and use `popupWindow.ShowAtLocation(view, GravityFlags.Center, x, y);`. @Elohist

Comment: Could you teach me how to get X and Y location of anchor object? I trying to search it on internet but I could not find xamarin.android code

Comment: I had test just now, you can try to use  `popupWindow.ShowAtLocation(imagebutton, GravityFlags.NoGravity, 0, 0);` @Elohist

Comment: It shows at the top left corner only.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, please check the update in the answer.@Elohist